# Maggiore e più grande

Tags: difference, meaning, adjectives, comparison

Ho visto diverse volte la parola "maggiore", ma ho anche visto "più grande" molte volte. C'è qualche differenza tra "maggiore" e "più grande" o è una scelta mia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La storia viene da lontano, cioè dal latino. Gli aggettivi *bonus*, *malus*, *magnus* e *parvus* avevano forme del comparativo prese da altri aggettivi ormai in disuso:

- *bonus/melior/optimus*
- *malus/peior/pessimus*
- *magnus/maior/maximus*
- *parvus/minor/minimus*

A dire il vero, per *magnus* si tratta solo di varianti, la radice è sempre *mag*.

Queste forme, proprio perché diverse dal modo usuale di formare comparativo e superlativo, come *purus/purior/purissimus*, sono passate in italiano come forme indipendenti, con significato leggermente distinto dalla forma normale con *più*.

Così in matematica si adoperano *maggiore* e *minore* con un certo significato tecnico e *maggiore* si trova in certe forme cristallizzate come *fratello minore* o *sorella maggiore*. Non è certo raro, però, sentire *mia sorella più grande*.

In italiano *malus* non ha dato esito e si dice *cattivo*, ma rimangono *peggiore* e *pessimo*. Così per *parvus*, per il quale usiamo *piccolo*.

Le forme più comuni sono, credo, *migliore* e *peggiore*, mentre *maggiore* e *minore* sono adoperate quasi solo nei sensi speciali detti prima (non sono gli unici).

Non sbagli se dici *più grande*, potresti dicendo *maggiore*, almeno nella lingua “di tutti i giorni” (escludendo i linguaggi settoriali). Nota che *maggiore* come sostantivo ha il significato arcaico di *antenato*: *chi fuor li maggior tui?* chiede Farinata degli Uberti a Dante. In questo caso ovviamente non si può sostituire altro.

Comment: Però, riferendomi all'ultimo capoverso, *chi furono i tuoi grandi*, in un contesto poetico, facilmente porta a pensare ad antenati che abbiano avuto un peso nella storia.

Answer (score 3):

Secondo Maria Cristina Peccianti, *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* (Giunti Editori, 2013):

> Gli aggettivi qualificativi ***buono***, ***cattivo***, ***grande***, ***piccolo***, oltre ad avere le normali forme di comparativo e superlativo, hanno anche **forme speciali** che non derivano dall'aggettivo di base, ma dal latino. Nell'uso le due forme sono equivalenti: *Gregorio è **il più grande** dei miei nipoti, Claudio invece è **il minore***.

Sempre secondo Maria Cristina Peccianti, per l'aggettivo *grande* esistono queste forme equivalenti di comparativo di maggioranza e di superlativo:

> - **Comparativo di maggioranza**: *più grande/maggiore*.
> - **Superlativo relativo**: *il più grande/il maggiore*.
> - **Superlativo assoluto**: *grandissimo/massimo*.

Answer (score 2):

Sono equivalenti, ma a volte uno suona meglio dell'altro... Per esempio, puoi dire "mio fratello maggiore",  però se dovessi fare un paragone fra due cose/persone, io userei "più grande".  Esempio:  io sono più grande di te,  la mia casa è più grande della tua, etc.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Orlando!